# How to know when to divide stem and leafs into two parts?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

By two parts I mean when each stem is divided into low and high. For example in this question, do I need to divide each stem into two parts? What are the rules? Also is it positive or negative skew?

For the following data set, construct a stem-and-leaf plot by hand.

```
373     370     364     366     364     325     339      393 
356     359     363     375     424     325     394      402
392     369     374     359     356     403     334      397
```

For example

32L |

32H| 5 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like a histogram: there is no absolute rule.

Just do what seems sensible (here not dividing) and see if there are too many leaves (too short to convey meaning) or too few leaves (which will be too long); if so, adjust your plot.

As for the skewness, you should do the plot and then consider what you see.